# How to make a ipa in react native app? without local development server

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I have completed process done which given by react native site.and still not getting ipa for without local host server build.

Comment: What you've done?

Comment: I have done by me (react-native verison 0.50.0)
1.edit scheme to release mode. 
2. run on command 
"react-native bundle --dev false --entry-file index.ios.js --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --platform ios"
3.developer provisioning profile create for adhoc and development both.
4.archive build.
5.Install but crash on splash screen.

Comment: So please provide error log.

Comment: [error][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] undefined is not an object  Unhandled JS Exception: undefined is not an object (evaluating exception 'RCTFatalException: Unhandled JS Exception: undefined is not an object (evaluating 's.View.propTypes.style')', reason: 'Unhandled JS Exception: undefined is not an object (evaluating 's.View.prop..., stack:

Answer (score 1):

This is the well-known issue of RN version 50.x these days. You can found it [App force close on release mode](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/1348) and [React Native 0.50.1 - Release Crash](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/1348) .

Currently there is some commits to resolve this such as [PropTypes issue - fix for #1348](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/pull/1382).

There are also some workaround solution:

1. Downgrade RN to 49.x version.
2. `Uglify-js` tag a version 3.1.9 that fix the issue, just add this code into `package.json`

   ```
   "resolutions": {
       "metro-bundler": "0.20.2",
       "color-convert": "1.9.1",
       "uglify-js": "github:alexlamsl/UglifyJS2#issue-2449"
   },
   ```

Comment: Thanks resolved but view.props.style error is deprecated.
and i have resolved this.

Comment: @rvios so can you tell me how to fix it please? I want to know